# Tab-based wpf multithreaded application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm creating a tab-based application (like web browsers). The content of each tab can have very heavy rendering (like videos, maybe some scripts), so executing all tabs rendering in single thread causes UI lags. So I look in multithreaded application direction. Creating windows in separate threads is an easy task, but how to get them the tabbed-look?

> In fact there is another reason, that heavy rendering, to have separate thread for each tab. But it`s too complicated to explain in few words. Just believe me :)
>
> One more reason: if something blocks UI thread in one tab, the other tabs still can operate and we can close dead tab without losing others.

Comment: Please fix the typo: "windows in separate windows". Separate threads or processes?

Comment: Fixed. Separate threads

Comment: Is it really the *rendering* that is bothering you, performance-wise? In a tabbed UI, usually the contents of only one tab are visible at a time, so there is no requirement for any rendering to take place on the other tabs.

Comment: In fact no. But i can`t explain exactly (at least in English) why i need one thread for each tab. So let`s assume, that the problem is rendering :)

Comment: It is not possible to nest content from different threads in wpf.

Comment: @Gusdor Not exactly. [Here explaind how](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx) But you are not getting input events.

Comment: @GorRustamyan that still reads as `not possible` to me. Displaying a bitmap achieves the same thing. Better to ensure that invisible elements are not rendered (the wpf `TabControl` _already does this_)

Comment: You might be interested in an updated discussion of some of these issues here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2013/02/26/mitigating-airspace-issues-in-wpf-applications.aspx

Comment: @NicholasW Very interesting article with many interesting low-level win32 detail. Thanks